Product evaluation using telescoping
$$
{\bf\mbox{Question}}:\qquad
\prod_{i = 1}^{2019}\left(2^{2^{\LARGE i}} - 2^{2^{\LARGE i - 1}} + 1\right)
$$
My approach:
I think we have to make a telescoping product:
$$
\mbox{Let}\ 2^{i} = t.\qquad
2^{t} - 2^{t/2} + 1\ \stackrel{t\ =\ 2u}{=}\
2^{2u} -2^{u} +1
$$
Failed.
If we factor this, we go in complex numbers.
Another approach:
I tried to just write out the terms for any pattern:
$\mbox{For}\ i = 1, 3\
\mbox{for}\ i = 2, 13$.
But I cannot get any pattern this way too.
Another Approach:
I tried rationalizing, so that we can get something in the denominator to cancel out. But that did not work too.
Is there any easier way ?.

Clarifying question 1: Product notation is ambiguous without parentheses here. Which of these do you intend?
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{2019} \left( 2^{2^i} - 2^{2^{i-1}} \right) + 1 \neq
\prod_{i=1}^{2019} \left( 2^{2^i} - 2^{2^{i-1}} + 1 \right)
$$

Clarifying question 2: You refer to "telescoping sum". Presumably, you intend to ask about "telescoping product"?

@SammyBlack sorry, edited both

There are some solutions on AoPS, which can be found with Approach0

$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^4+2x^2+1)-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
Plug in suitable powers of $2$ in place of $x$.

May be computing in mod 7 ?

I don't want to fully solve your question but here's a hint:
$$(a^{2^i}-a^{2^{i-1}}+1)(a^{2^i}+a^{2^{i-1}}+1)=a^{2^{i+1}}+a^{2^i}+1$$
